# Accepted socket from task failing in other process

Tags: sockets, elixir, gen-tcp

I'm trying to test some elixir code and came across some behavior of gen_tcp I don't understand. When I gen_tcp.accept a socket I may "access" it in the task I created it in, but not a different one. I figured this was a "controlling_process" issue but even when I added that any attempt to use :inet.getstat results in an invalid argument error. I also cannot do a receive on the socket, Elixir claims it's closed but for this question getstat was easier. See below:

```
defmodule ElixirQuestion do
  def serve_one_client(socket, pid) 
  do  
    {:ok, server_socket} = :gen_tcp.accept(socket)
    :ok = :gen_tcp.controlling_process(server_socket, pid)
    IO.inspect(:inet.getstat(server_socket))
    server_socket 
  end 
end

{:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.listen(0, [:binary, 
                                      {:packet, :raw}, 
                                      {:active, false}])
{:ok, port_number} = :inet.port(socket)
server_task = Task.async(fn -> ElixirQuestion.serve_one_client(socket, self()) end)
{:ok, _client_socket} = :gen_tcp.connect('localhost', port_number, [active: false]) 
server_socket = Task.await(server_task)

IO.inspect(:inet.getstat(server_socket))
```

Expected output

```
{:ok,
 [recv_oct: 0, recv_cnt: 0, recv_max: 0, recv_avg: 0, recv_dvi: 0, send_oct: 0,
  send_cnt: 0, send_max: 0, send_avg: 0, send_pend: 0]}
{:ok,
 [recv_oct: 0, recv_cnt: 0, recv_max: 0, recv_avg: 0, recv_dvi: 0, send_oct: 0,
  send_cnt: 0, send_max: 0, send_avg: 0, send_pend: 0]}
```

Received output

```
{:ok,
 [recv_oct: 0, recv_cnt: 0, recv_max: 0, recv_avg: 0, recv_dvi: 0, send_oct: 0,
  send_cnt: 0, send_max: 0, send_avg: 0, send_pend: 0]}
{:error, :einval}
```

Elixir version

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3.5.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.4.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self()` inside `Task.async` will return the PID of the `Task` process. Since you want the value of the parent process here, you need to save this value outside the fn passed to `Task.async` and then use that inside.

Changing:

```
server_task = Task.async(fn -> ElixirQuestion.serve_one_client(socket, self()) end)
```

to:

```
me = self()
server_task = Task.async(fn -> ElixirQuestion.serve_one_client(socket, me) end)
```

gives me the output you expect:

```
{:ok,
 [recv_oct: 0, recv_cnt: 0, recv_max: 0, recv_avg: 0, recv_dvi: 0, send_oct: 0,
  send_cnt: 0, send_max: 0, send_avg: 0, send_pend: 0]}
{:ok,
 [recv_oct: 0, recv_cnt: 0, recv_max: 0, recv_avg: 0, recv_dvi: 0, send_oct: 0,
  send_cnt: 0, send_max: 0, send_avg: 0, send_pend: 0]}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be something that I would be miffed at when I got the answer! Thanks a ton!